# how to compare two conditions in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In code:

```
<% @line_item.each do |line_item| %>
  <% id=line_item.menu_id%>
  <% @menu1=Menu.find(id)%>
  <%= @menu_name = @menu1.menu_item_name%>
<% @offers.each do |offer| %>
**<% if offer.menuName_buy1 == @menu_name && offer.menuName_buy2 == @menu_name %>**
```

I am new in rails.I want to compare `menuName_buy1`  & `menuName_buy2` with `@menu_name`, but how do i achieve this result.At a time i am getting 1 value for `@menu_name`.

Comment: Can you put comment where you want to compaire @manu_name also relation between all models you used here for `<%= @menu_name= @menu1.menu_item_name%>` you can use `<%= @menu_name= line_item.menu.menu_item_name%>`

Comment: what r u asking?I can't understand.

Comment: I want to compare `<% if offer.menuName_buy1 == @menu_name && offer.menuName_buy2 == @menu_name %>`

Comment: I say you can remove this three line code `<% id=line_item.menu_id%>
  <% @menu1=Menu.find(id)%>
  <%= @menu_name = @menu1.menu_item_name%>` to one line like this `<%= @menu_name= line_item.menu.menu_item_name%>` Can you provide association between models so easy to know compairision is possible or not